# How to trigger an event handler from within another event, C#

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

So I have a form where I want to change the position of a trackbar and trigger the trackbar_scroll event after I click on a label. So far, clicking on the label changed the value of the trackbar, thats easy:

```
        private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            trackBar1.Value = 0;
        }
        private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (trackBar1.Value == 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    //code...
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error occured");
                }
            }
        }
```

How do I call the trackBar1_scroll(..) event from within the label click?

Answer (score 9):

Try calling it directly.  You just have to supply the parameters yourself:

```
trackBar1_Scroll(trackBar1, EventArgs.Empty);
```

or simply

```
trackBar1_Scroll(null, null);
```

if the parameters are not being utilized.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach you could take, aside from @LarsTech answer (which is absolutely correct), would be to refactor your code to reduce the need to supply empty parameters.  Since you're not actually using the EventArgs or referencing the *sender* directly, given your example above, you could do something like the following:

```
private void DoSomething(int value)
{
   ...
}

private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DoSomething(trackBar1.Value);
}

private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DoSomething(...);
}
```

It always feels like *code smell* to me, when you call an event handler with empty parameters, simply to execute code which you could otherwise abstract out.

Comment: +1 When coding, I actually do something more along the lines of your answer than my own answer.